# ARIMA PACF plot interpretation

Tags: time-series, arima, model-selection, acf-pacf

I have this dataset about voters in a country

[image: Voters for party A]

There is a clear trend therefore I differentiate the data once to achieve a stationary data

[image: 1st difference]

The resulting acf and pacf plots are below

[image]

Based on my understanding, ACF cuts off at lag 1 while PACF tails off. Thus, this suggests a model of ARIMA(0,1,1)

Below is the ACF and PACF of ARIMA(0,1,1)

[image]

How do I interpret the PACF for significant lag 4? From what I have learnt, PACF plot should suggest the AR model. However, only lag 4 is significant.

Additionally, below is the parameter estimate of the ARIMA(0,1,1).

[image]

The p-value of the parameter MA1 suggests that something is not captured by the model. Does this mean that something is not captured by the ARIMA model?

Below is the acf and pacf after removing the linear trend

[image]

Edit: added the acf and pacf plot for the original data
Edit2: added the acf and pacf plot after removing trend

Comment: Is the trend in the data deterministic or stochastic? In the former case, differencing would result in overdifferencing which is something to be avoided. Negative ACF(1), PACF(1) coefficients of differenced data is symptomatic of that.

Comment: Hi im learning from this website: https://people.duke.edu/~rnau/arimrule.htm
Based on rule 2, it says that the series may be overdifferenced if the autocorrelation is -0.5 or more. Hence, I did not think about the effects of the trend in the data being deterministic or stochastic.

However, based on the acf and pacf of the original data, the acf tails off while pacf has a significant lag 1. Hence, I did an ARIMA(1,0,0). However, on my pacf, there is still a significant lag 4 similar to the pacf i posted above. How do I interpret this?

Comment: So you did ARIMA(1,0,0) on original data? I think you wrote *therefore I differentiate the data once to achieve a stationary data* which is not the same. You could try removing a linear trend from the original data and then checking ACF and PACF.

Comment: I have removed the linear trend from the original data and there are no significant lags on the acf. The pacf still has a significant lag 4. What does this mean for my data?